# Loop through table in SQL Server and update a column at a specific count index

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm trying to update a column value using the value below it and I'm using a loop to try and achieve this.please see screen shot of the field I'm trying to update.

i.e I'm trying to update the 2nd line of Details into the 1st line reference.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GD7V2.png]

```
DECLARE @CTRw INT
SET @CTRw = 2

WHILE @CTRw <= 600
BEGIN
    UPDATE [SBSA_Loaded] 
    SET Reference  = LEFT(Details, 50) 
    WHERE ID = @CTRw

    --DELETE FROM [SBSA_Loaded] WHERE id = @CTRw

    PRINT @CTRw 

    -- SELECT id, details FROM [SBSA_Loaded] WHERE ID = @CTR
    SET @CTRw += 2
END
```

Comment: Read about `LEAD()` and `LAG()`. In general: Avoid loops whenever possible...

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: @Shnugo thanks it did the trick, never knew about those functions.

Comment: @Shnugo thanks it did the trick, never knew about those functions.

Answer (score 3):

I know lead maybe the answer here. But I always did this using a self join on ID+1

I see what you are doing and this will get it done without loops:

Step 1 - Update Reference with the next row:

```
Update main
set Reference = left(next.Details,50)
from SBSA_Loaded main
join SSBA_Loaded next on main.ID+1=next.ID
```

Step 2 - Delete Even number rows:

```
Delete from SBSA_Loaded
where ID % 2 = 0  --MOD looks at the remainder of division
```

Comment: LEAD() and LAG() may not be available in every environment so it is still good to know how to do it in other ways.

Comment: `WHERE main.Page = 1`

Comment: If you cannot rely on gapless numbers you might place a `CTE` first calling `ROW_NUMBER()` sorted by the existing ID and use this CTE as source for your `self-join` construction.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using modus `%` and `lead`

```
declare @T table (pk int identity primary key, descr varchar(20), val 

varchar(20));
insert into @T (descr) VALUES ('odd description'), ('even description'), ('odd description'), ('even description'), ('odd description'), ('even description'), ('odd description')
                            , ('even description'), ('odd description'), ('even description'), ('odd description'), ('even description'), ('odd description'), ('even description')
                            , ('odd description'), ('even description'), ('odd description'), ('even description'), ('odd description'), ('even description'), ('odd description');
select *
     , pk % 2 as modus
from @T t;

with cte as 
( select *
       , lead(descr) over (order by pk) as leadDescr
  from @T t
)

update t 
set val = LEFT(leadDescr, 4)
from CTE t 
where pk % 2 = 1;

select *
from @T t;

pk          descr                val                  modus
----------- -------------------- -------------------- -----------
1           odd description      NULL                 1
2           even description     NULL                 0
3           odd description      NULL                 1
4           even description     NULL                 0
5           odd description      NULL                 1
6           even description     NULL                 0
7           odd description      NULL                 1
8           even description     NULL                 0
9           odd description      NULL                 1
10          even description     NULL                 0
11          odd description      NULL                 1
12          even description     NULL                 0
13          odd description      NULL                 1
14          even description     NULL                 0
15          odd description      NULL                 1
16          even description     NULL                 0
17          odd description      NULL                 1
18          even description     NULL                 0
19          odd description      NULL                 1
20          even description     NULL                 0
21          odd description      NULL                 1

pk          descr                val
----------- -------------------- --------------------
1           odd description      even
2           even description     NULL
3           odd description      even
4           even description     NULL
5           odd description      even
6           even description     NULL
7           odd description      even
8           even description     NULL
9           odd description      even
10          even description     NULL
11          odd description      even
12          even description     NULL
13          odd description      even
14          even description     NULL
15          odd description      even
16          even description     NULL
17          odd description      even
18          even description     NULL
19          odd description      even
20          even description     NULL
21          odd description      NULL
```